# DAC Connection using the SSMS for executing the code

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014, sqlcmd, xp-cmdshell

Can anyone help me on below . I am trying to execute the SQLCMD with DAC (-A switch) but unable to do so .

How can I do it both ways below :

1. Execute in SSMS Query Pane
2. Execute using PowerShell

Below is what I have tried with no luck .

```
EXEC master.dbo.xp_cmdshell "SQLCMD -S SQLServer -d Db1 -A
go
select count(*) AS FileCount from TableName
go"
```

### output

> 'select' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file. NULL

### Message

> Msg 103, Level 15, State 4, Line 1 The identifier that starts with '

```
SQLCMD -S SQLServer -d Db1 -A
go
select count(*) AS FileCount' is too long. Maximum length is 128.
```

Comment: Quick question: Why do you want to run a command in SSMS via `SQLCMD` with `DAC`? Why not just open a query window with `DAC`?

Comment: @hot2use , I am trying to check filecount which are marked in FileStream Garbage collection tombstone table which needs to accessed only by DAC connection. When I tried to access ADMIN:Server , it is somewhat saying me , it cannot connect . In this case I am using SQLCMD with -A switch . Same thing I am trying to do it with powershell which I am not able to . So I am looking for ways to execute multiple line of code using SSMS and even powershell . Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass in your query according to `sqlcmd` syntax specifying `-Q` (or `-q` or `-i` for the script file) like this:

```
EXEC master.dbo.xp_cmdshell 'SQLCMD -S SQLServer -A -d Db1 -Q"select count(*) AS FileCount from TableName" '
```

Comment: Thanks , this did help me . Anyways which I can do the same thing in Windows PowerShell . For ex : How can I execute SQLCMD from Invoke-SQLCMD ? Many thanks